# Media files are served, static files aren't

Tags: django, static-files, django-staticfiles

I'm stuck due to [an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618611/serving-django-static-files-in-development-envirnoment) [evergreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602263/serving-static-files-for-development-mode-in-django) [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806287/serving-static-files-in-django-development), static files not served. Conversely the files placed in the `MEDIA_ROOT` subtree get served correctly under `MEDIA_URL`.

Stripped `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/foo/devel/static'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/foo/devel/media'
# the following is deprecated but is it seems grappelly requires it
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "grappelli/"
STATIC_FILES = ()
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

To create the project I did:

```
$ cd /home/foo/devel/
$ virtualenv testdrive
$ . bin/activate; pip install django; cd testdrive
$ django-admin.py fbtest
```

and got this directory tree (stripped):

```
. <-- /home/foo/devel/
├── bin
├── fbtest
│   └── fbtest
│       ├── media
│       │   └── foo.jpg
│       ├── static
│       └────── foo.jpg
├── include
└── lib
```

Files under `STATIC_URL` should be served automatically by Django staticfiles (not in my case), while other files have to be handled manually. So I appended these lines to `urls.py`:

```
import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip("/"),
            'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

Accessing `http://host/media/filebrowser/foo.jpg` works, while `http://host/static/foo.jpg` gives error 404. Why?

Comment: What wersion of django you use?

Comment: Can you add in `INSTALLED_APPS` to the stripped settings.py file?

Comment: Can you explain what "evergreen" means here? Google was useless.

Comment: @JordanReiter thanks for the pointer, the problem was there indeed. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11005313/573034).

Comment: Sorry. I meant a classic issue discussed very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly error. I forgot to add `fbtest` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, so the static file machinery didn't manage static files for this app.

Answer (score 6):

> Files under `STATIC_URL` should be served automatically by Django staticfiles (not in my case), while other files have to be handled manually.

That's incorrect. Django never serves `STATIC_ROOT` ever -- not even in development. What it *does* do is make files in each app's "static" directory and files in any directory specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` available at `STATIC_URL`. You don't actually manually put anything in `STATIC_ROOT` ever; in fact, in development, you shouldn't even have the directory there. Put simply, `STATIC_ROOT` is only a dumping ground for your static files *in production* when you run the `collectstatic` management command.

In development, all static files should go into `someapp/static`, where "someapp" is the app they apply to. In the case that the files apply to the project as a whole, a global CSS file for example, you need to create an entirely different directory (i.e. *not* the same as `STATIC_ROOT` or `MEDIA_ROOT`) and then add that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. For example, I normally call mine "assets", so:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets'),
)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great explanation, now things are even more clear.

Comment: @Chris Pratt : How do you refer to an app that is in `someapp/static`? For me, `STATIC_URL` can only reach files available in `STATIC_ROOT` (Django 1.3).

Comment: @Mr.Dave: is this in development or production. In development, remove the `STATIC_ROOT` directory completely. I've noticed Django tends to serve files from there in development *if* it exists, instead of actually referencing all the app's static directories and anything in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. In production, just run `collectstatic` to have everything copied there, and then serve that directory with your web server.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Thanks, I think that was causing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is realy evergreen... 
Some hints:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    # ...
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ... 
)
```

- Did you use? [django-admin-collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) command?
- Can you help add [show_indexes=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#django.views.static.serve) in url settings?
- Some symbolic link?
- Run app with --adminmedia=../grappelli/static/grappelli arg.?

My settings for django 1.4 (no grappelli):

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip('/'), 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, "show_indexes": True}),

        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "show_indexes": True}),

    ) + urlpatterns
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    # ...
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks. _1._ I tried but didn't help. _2._ Neither adding `show_indexes: True` to the dictionary. _3._ YES, virtualenv creates a `local` directory containing these links: `bin -> /home/foo/devel/testdrive/bin`, `include -> /home/foo/devel/testdrive/include` and `lib -> /home/foo/devel/testdrive/lib`. _4._ Sorry I don't know how to use --adminmedia option.

Comment: python manage.py runserver --adminmedia=../path-to-grappelli/grappelli/static/grappelli

Comment: adminmedia is base djago command... [=>docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---adminmedia)

Comment: try to set MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/foo/devel/fbtest/fbtest/media'

Comment: Setting MEDIA_ROOT to that value doesn't fix the /static/ problem and breaks the /media/ serving, which previously worked. Let me investigate about the missing --adminmedia option...

Comment: The docs for Django 1.4 [cites --adminmedia](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---adminmedia), but `python manage.py help runserver` doesn't list the option. So I assume it is not available in 1.4.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12467/discussion-between-guandalino-and-dingo)