# Django not loading CSS?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

This is my urls.py

```
import os.path
site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    { 'document_root': site_media }),
)
```

My site_media folder and style.css file is in

```
myProjectFolder/myApp/static/site_media/css/style.css
```

and in my base.html template (all my other templates extend off of this base.html template) this is what I have:

```
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/site_media/css/style.css' />
</head>

<body>
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <div id='header'></div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

and in my style.css, all I have is this:

```
#header {
    display: inline;
    background-color: black;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

and the CSS is not being applied to the

```
#header
```

div. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from 2 areas.

1. wrong document_root variable passed
2. not using template tags in html

1.
Defining site_media variable in urls.py file is discouraged as it does not adhere to DRY principle. It should be held as a variable in your settings.py file so other modules may import if needed.
In your settings.py file, add the following line:

```
import os.path
SITE_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myApp/', 'static/', 'site_media' #this should be the correct path instead
)
```

Replace your urls.py file with this:

```
from myApp import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{ 'document_root': settings.SITE_MEDIA_ROOT }),
)
```

2.You should use django template tags to get the css file. In your base template, add this line above the head tag:

```
{% load static %}
```

Then replace:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/site_media/css/style.css' />
```

with:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'site_media/css/style.css' %}" />
```

After which it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You can modify a little bit your code in urls.py

in urls.py

```
site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)
```

to

```
site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), "../", "myApp", "static", 'site_media'
)
```

2. Remove

```
site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)
```

and add

```
{% load static %} at the beginning of base.html
```

and change

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/site_media/css/style.css' />
```

to

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'site_media/css/style.css' %}" />
```

The second method is preferable.
Here is working code: https://github.com/lukaszszajkowski/s21083672

Here are links to documentation and reading:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files
[Media files are served, static files aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004239/media-files-are-served-static-files-arent)